# The method getSubmittedFileName() is undefined for the type Part

Tags: java, file-upload, servlet-3.0

I am trying to upload multiple files in servlet 3.0>. I am getting an error at getSubmittedFileName() method. Why am I getting this error?

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    String description = request.getParameter("description"); // Retrieves
                                                                // <input
                                                                // type="text"
                                                                // name="description">
    Part filePart = request.getPart("file"); // Retrieves <input type="file"
                                                // name="file">
    String fileName = Paths.get(filePart.getSubmittedFileName())
            .getFileName().toString(); // MSIE fix.
    InputStream fileContent = filePart.getInputStream();
    // ... (do your job here)
}
```

Comment: finally i can found solution,
change your **tomcat server** vershion you can solved this problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got this problem before.
Some guy helped me to find the root of this issue, so here is the solution I got:

In the DOC of Java EE 7 you can see that the 'Interface Part' has been added to it getSubmittedFileName method since Servlet 3.1, and from tomcat website you can see that Tomcat 7 implemented Servlet 3.0, so I needed to upgrade from Tomcat 7 to Tomcat 8.0.x.

References:

- [getSubmittedFileName of Part Interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/Part.html#getSubmittedFileName--)
- [Tomcat Versions](http://tomcat.apache.org/whichversion.html)

Comment: i had tomcat 8 and using java 8

Comment: Have you changed your project "Targeted Runtimes": https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B2GmsAlF3bu_dTRDc19iTHlVYWc

Comment: Amm, Okay
When you get to the issue again we can start troubleshooting it again.
servlet 3.1 is not used by Tomcat 8.

Comment: These days i am working as android developer in a company.So i am all about android android android

Answer (score 3):

If you're using Servlet 3.0, you will have to define the `getSubmittedFileName()` manually.

Scroll down in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2424824) to "**When you're not on Servlet 3.1 yet, manually get submitted file name**" for the method definition and change it according to your needs.

Answer (score 2):

i have gone through this problem,
simply apply this dependancy in maven pom.xml file...

```
     <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/javax.servlet-api -->
     <dependency>
         <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
          <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
          <version>3.1.0</version>
          <scope>provided</scope>
       </dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

If somebody like me came here having `getSubmittedFileName()` null in a

`for (Part filePart : request.getParts())` loop

then just know that not every `Part` has a `FileName` property :)